# Install LocalDB with deployment project

Tags: deployment, sql-server-2012, localdb

I'm upgrading my application to use SQL Server 2012 Express LocalDB instead of SQL CE 4.

I already have a setup project with a bootstrapper to install the requirements (.NET Framework, Windows Installer).

How do I include the LocalDB.msi and .NET 4.0.2 in my deployment project?

Comment: I found the Bootstrapper package for LocalDB in the VS 11 Beta, but nothing official for .NET 4.0.2. I'll try and create my own Package.xml and Product.xml. Shipping with .NET 4.5 Beta is not an option for me.

Comment: When building the .NET 4.0.2 bootstrapper keep in mind that Windows 8 already comes with .NET 4.5, so you only need to install 4.0.2 on Windows Vista and Windows 7.

Comment: I don't think any of our customers are using Win 8 right now. In fact, some are still using XP and I have a bad feeling about deploying my app with LocalDB, as that would shut them out.

Comment: It is perfectly fine to wait with migrating to LocalDB until your customers are on Windows version it supports. As to Windows 8, sure, it hasn't shipped yet, so no customers are using it now. I was just suggesting to build the installer in a future-proof way by handling the case of Windows 8 properly. I guess it is fine to ignore it for now, assuming you will have time to refresh and distribute your application before your customers start using Windows 8.

Answer (score 0):

Since i know LocalDB not need any prerequisites, so you just use empty 
`<Product ...>` tag in product.xml in this Address:

> C:\Program Files [(x86)]\Microsoft
>   SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages\